# jQuery DateTime picker issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery DateTime picker on one of my View. This DateTime picker is working fine on one PC. On another PC it is giving error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

The jQuery code and this View itself is same on both the PCs. Even the jQuery versions are same.

Below is the code:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready (function () {
        $(".fromdate").datepicker();
    })
</script>
```

The only difference I could see is in the App_Start folder.
The PC on which this error is shown has only one file in this folder and that is RouteConfig.cs

The other PC on which it is working fine has couple of files in this folder including BundleConfig.cs

Is it anything has to do with this?

Comment: you need to have jquery and jquery validate in the scripts folder

Comment: Are you using the bundles anywhere in the view or its layout - e.g `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` or similar?

Comment: @madalinivascu Both are there in the Scripts folder.

Comment: @StephenMuecke In Layout I have:    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> I am not using elsewhere.

Comment: For a start you have duplicated your `jquery-1.10.2.js` file which will be a problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nice catch Stephen. Please post this as answer so that I can mark it as solution. It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, you have included `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` in your layout. The duplicate `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` needs to be removed since the order of the scripts is important. I also recommend you make use of the excellent bundling and minification features of MVC as explained in [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).